# Prolog permutations of size M - ERROR: Out of global stack

Tags: prolog

I want this code to output permutations (with repetition) of the letters a, b, and c.

```
letter('a').
letter('b').
letter('c').

f(0,L,L).

f(N,L0,L):-
  append(L0,[X],L1),
  letter(X),
  N1 is N-1,
  f(N1,L1,L).

f(N,L):-
  f(N,[],L).
```

When I execute it like so

```
?- f(3,L).
L = [a, a, a] ;
```

The first answer is correct, but when I try to backtrack for more answers I receive the error:

```
ERROR: Out of global stack
```

I can see that the error is because my counter N is decremented from 0 to - 1 when backtracking, but I thought the interpreter would backtrack to when N was positive, thus preventing this from happening.

Can anyone explain what is going wrong? Thanks

Comment: Why would the interpreter increment `N` on backtrack? It only does what you tell it to do, which in this case, is decrement (`N1 is N - 1`). If you do a `trace`, you will be able to see why it is failing. The problem isn't really a backtrack issue but you recursively call `f` with an ever decreasing value of `N` with no check that it goes negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your recursive call to `f/3` occurs with ever-decreasing values of `N` without ever checking that it is non-negative. Try:

```
f(N, L0, L):-
    N >= 0,              % add this
    append(L0, [X], L1),
    letter(X),
    N1 is N-1,
    f(N1, L1, L).
```